# Using users ringtones

Tags: iphone, ringtone

I was looking for a way to use user's tones that were transfered manually from the Itunes.
I know that it's impossible to use Apple system tones but i want to use only users privet tones.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the users ringtones, not even the custom ringtones added via iTunes. There is no API that will allow this.